# Yii2 Query Builder with ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have three models `Employer` , `Job`, and `Transaction`

`Employer` can have many `Job`

`Job` can have many `Transaction`

I am trying to use ActiveRecord to get all `Employer` that do not have a `Transaction` record.

Within my Employer model, I have defined relations to find all jobs and transactions linked to this employer:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getJobs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Job::className(), ['employer_id' => 'employer_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTransactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::className(), ['job_id' => 'job_id'])->via("jobs");
}
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL:

```sql
SELECT employer.* 
FROM   employer 
WHERE  employer.employer_id NOT IN 
(
  SELECT employer.employer_id 
  FROM employer 
    INNER JOIN job         ON employer.employer_id = job.employer_id
    INNER JOIN transaction ON           job.job_id = transaction.job_id
)
```

With Yii2:

```
function getThoseWithoutTransaction() {
    return Employer::find()->where(['not in', 'employer_id', 
        (new Query())
            ->select('employer.employer_id')
            ->from('employer')
            ->innerJoin('job', 'employer.employer_id = job.employer_id')
            ->innerJoin('transaction', 'job.job_id = transaction.job_id')
        )]
    );
}
```

But I didn't test it. Hope it is correct, though. And there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$query = MyModel::find()->where(['not in','attribute',$array]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm looking to get all Employers which don't have transactions (through job)

Comment: If in the $array you have the distinct Employers which have transation and in attribute the employer_id this is the righit solution